# Why don't the links in my app work? They should open the browser or an app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, xcode, cordova

Good Morning,

I have created my application with Gdevelop and I have passed it through Cordova to be able to run it from XCODE.

It works correctly, but it doesn't open the links when you click on the image. It's made with JS and on Android and PC it works normally. I attach part of the code to see if you can help me in the iOS part.

Thank you very much!

};gdjs.InicioCode.mapOfGDgdjs_9546InicioCode_9546GDTikTokObjects4Objects = Hashtable.newFrom({"TikTok": gdjs.InicioCode.GDTikTokObjects4});
gdjs.InicioCode.eventsList12 = function(runtimeScene) {

```
{
let isConditionTrue_0 = false;
isConditionTrue_0 = false;
{isConditionTrue_0 = runtimeScene.getOnceTriggers().triggerOnce(47625948);
}
if (isConditionTrue_0) {
{gdjs.evtTools.window.openURL("https://www.tiktok.com/@stiluproject", runtimeScene);
}}
```